# imagecreatefromstring fails while successful in .NET

Tags: php, gd2

I have an image that is base64 encoded. Decoding this image through C# works like a charm with the following code:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(decodeImageForm.Data);
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

// Convert byte[] to Image
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
pbImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

However, when trying to decode the same text in PHP using the following code

```
$payload = "..."; // same text as used above
$data = base64_decode($payload);    
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false)
{
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   imagepng($im);
   imagedestroy($im);       
}
else 
{        
    die("Failed to create image from string. ".strlen($payload));
}
```

it fails with the following warning:

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

Here is the GD section of phpinfo()

- GD Support enabled
- GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
- FreeType Support enabled
- FreeType Linkage with freetype
- FreeType Version 2.4.6
- T1Lib Support enabled
- GIF Read Support enabled
- GIF Create Support enabled
- JPEG Support enabled
- libJPEG Version 6b
- PNG Support enabled
  libPNG Version 1.2.46
  WBMP Support enabled
  XBM Support enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0

What am I missing here? There are images that do work sometimes

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out the mime type of the image is x-bmp, which isn't supported by GD in PHP...
I was able to decode the string to an image resource through the [following link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php#53879) with slight modifications to accept a string stream rather than a filename.